# Why can't I change my MAC address?

Tags: kali-linux, network-interface, mac-address

I'm trying to change my MAC address using macchanger but it seems as if my device is not able to spoof a different address? I don't know but it seems as if no where has a solution to this.

```
root@kali:~# sudo macchanger -a wlan0                                                                                                                              
Current MAC:   XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (Apple)
Permanent MAC: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (Apple)
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Too many open files in system
root@kali:~#
```

What does this mean? 'interface up or insufficient permissions'. I've tried this:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo macchanger -a wlan0
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But I still get that error on the second command.

FYI:

```
root@kali:~# lspci | grep Wireless
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
root@kali:~#
```

Comment: As a comment and not an answer, but not all hardware allows setting the mac address.

Comment: How can I be sure that this is the problem? Is there a way to check whether my hardware can spoof? Also what is the alternative then if I need to change my MAC address?

Comment: The hardware is not the problem because I just tried it on OS X and it worked

Answer (score 2):

To change the MAC adress of the `wlan0` interface, run the following commands:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
ifconfig wlan0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Verify:

```
ifconfig wlan0 |grep HWadd
```

**Edit**

Edit the `70-persistent-net.rules` configuration file:

```
 nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Change the MAC adress:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
```

Replace `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` then reboot your machine.

**edit2**

Using `iproute2` Methode:

```
ip link set dev wlan0 down
ip link set dev wlan0 address XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
ip link set dev wlan0 up
```

Comment: SIOCSIFHWADDR: Too many open files in system

Comment: Even after running: ulimit -n 4096

Comment: root@kali:/etc/udev/rules.d# ls
70-persistent-cd.rules  73-usb-net-by-mac.rules

Comment: and 70-persistent-cd.rules is empty. 73-usb-net-by-mac.rules is a bash file

Comment: try  `systemd-udevd` https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MAC_address_spoofing

Comment: File doesn't exist

Comment: (edit2): RTNETLINK answers: Too many open files in system. This is what happens. As you can see its the same answer everytime. 'Too many open files in system' Has this got something to do with there being extra drivers I didn't need to use still there?

Comment: even with SpoofMac, same thing: root@kali:~# spoof-mac.py randomize wlan0
RTNETLINK answers: Too many open files in system